# Error 000204 using "Export Feature Attribute to ASCII" Tool on ArcGIS Server 10

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing, export, csv, ascii

I´m trying to export feature attributes to a CSV-File (on ArcGIS Server) to use them in other applications (using the "Export Feature Attribute to ASCII" Tool).
While the tool is working ok in a Desktop environment the published model always fails with the following error message:

ERROR 000204: Error creating input feature cursor

I have no idea how to deal with that or what might be the problem. Any suggestions?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don´t really know why, but when I changed the "Delimiter" from "SEMI-COLON" to "SPACE" it suddenly worked.

Once it worked, I changed it back to "SEMI-COLON" and guess what..... it keeps on working!
Isn´t this a strange world??